# Select dot separated text from a node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

What xslt methods are available to select text after several dots/characters in the textnode?

```
<con1:node>              
    <con2:node name="SomeName">
        <con2:path>'www.example.com.itsanexample.step1.step2.step3'</con2:path>
    </con2:node>
<con1:node>
```

For example `www.example.com.itsanexample.step1.step2.step3`

Where I want only the 4th word `step1` as output.

Comment: Well, find out which version of XSLT you want to use and then start with the documentation e.g. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/ for the current version or https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions if you are stuck with XSLT/XPath 1.0.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the 1.0 version.
Well I was trying to do that with substring, and it doesen't works. Like that's why I'm asking for advice what kind of methods are also usable.

Comment: If you're stuck with 1.0 and can't move to anything more recent, then check the str:tokenize named template on www.exslt.org.

Comment: Thanks, for advices!